# Is it possible to target a fieldtype by it's Type name, rather than the handle name?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype, twigextension

I've created an [Asset Source](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets) and assigned my own field via the field layout.

Then, I created an [Assets Field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields) to display a single image on a page. Using my plugins twig extension I can query the image object like so:

```
{{ entry.featuredImage.first()|myTwigExt }}
```

Now, in the Twig extension I want to target the first instance of my field using its Type, not the Handle.

[image]

The reason for this is because the handle can be defined by the user, but the type name is always the same. I want to **avoid** the need to parse in the field handle along with the Twig Extension like this:

```
{{ entry.featuredImage.first()|myTwigExt('notThis') }}
```

If this is even possible, my ideal situation would have my Twig Extension looking something like this:

```
  public function getFilters() {
    return array(
      'myTwigExt' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'myTwigExtension'),
    );
  }

  public function myTwigExtension($image, $param) {
   if ( $image->type('myCustomField') ) {
     // YAY!
     return $image->type('myCustomField')->someDataFromMyField;
   }

   if ( $image->$param ) {
     // "Boo!";
     return $image->$param->someDataFromMyField;
   }
  }
```

This is the cleanest way I can ask this question. Without going into too much detail about my plugin (which would just confuse the situation more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question correctly, so here is my understanding before I give my solution:

You want to be able to access a field on an asset by it's field type rather than it's handle.

Given this understanding, here is my solution:

I have not been able to accomplish this using Craft relations. However, you can loop through the fields attached to the asset, and check their type. It is a little bit confusing as Craft stores the data for fields and field layouts across several tables.

An element has a field layout ([FieldLayoutModel](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/FieldLayoutModel)), and the layout then has fields ([FieldLayoutFieldModels](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/FieldLayoutFieldModel)). Then each of those FieldLayoutFieldModels has fields ([FieldModel](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/FieldModel)) which are the actual fields we are looking for. Putting this together, we can loop through and check the field type like so:

```
    // get the fieldLayoutModel
    $fieldLayoutModel = $image->fieldLayout;

    // get array of FieldLayoutFieldModel
    $fieldLayoutFields = $fieldLayoutModel->fields;

    foreach($fieldLayoutFields as $fieldLayoutField){

        // get the field associated with the layout
        $field = $fieldLayoutField->field;
        if($field->type == 'myFieldType'){
            // do whatever
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Oh man, I could kiss you! When I tested this out and I was waiting for my page to refresh, I could feel my heart pumping... and then it just worked. Such a ball-ache, but very satisfying to see it can be done. Thank you very much 'kcolls'.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your plugin!

Comment: Bear in mind this will only get the first field of that type for the element.

Comment: That is true, but it can be easily modified to return all fields of that type.